# Put dplyr & ggplot in Loop/Apply

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm newish to R programming and am trying to standardise, or generalise, a piece of code so that I apply it to different data exports of the same structure. The code is trivial, but I am having trouble getting getting it to loop:

Here is my code:

```
plot <- data %>% 
  group_by(Age, ID) %>% 
  summarise(Rev = sum(TotalRevenue)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = AgeGroup,
    y = Rev,
    fill = AgeGroup
  )) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.9) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I want to generalise the code so that I can switch out 'Age'  w/ variables I put into a list. Here is my amateur code:

```
cols <- c(data$Col1, data$Col2) #Im pretty sure this is wrong

for (i in cols) {

plot <- data %>% 
  group_by(i, ID) %>% 
  summarise(Rev = sum(TotalRevenue)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = AgeGroup,
    y = Rev,
    fill = AgeGroup
  )) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.9) +
  theme_minimal()
}
```

And this doesn't work. The datasets I will be receiving will have the same variables, just different observations and so standardising this process will be a lifesaver.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably trying to do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

cols <- c('col1', 'col2')
plot_list <- lapply(cols, function(i) 
                  data %>% 
                   group_by(!!sym(i), ID) %>% 
                   summarise(Rev = sum(TotalRevenue)) %>%
                   ggplot(aes(x = AgeGroup,y = Rev,fill = AgeGroup))  +
                   geom_col(alpha = 0.9) + theme_minimal())
```

This will return you list of plots which can be accessed as `plot_list[[1]]`, `plot_list[[2]]` etc. Also look into facets to combine multiple plots.

Comment: The original póster probably needs to learn about non standard evaluation to make sense of !! (Pronounced bang bang) and sym().

Comment: Hi Ronak, answer worked perfectly and I have done some research into !! and sym(). Much appreciated!